# Django Translation - Translate dynamic strings

Tags: python, django

We are using `Django` as our backend `REST API` server. I am looking to translate text being sent as push notifications to our app. I am new to translations.

The text resides in a config file and varies for each user.

```
NOTIFICATION_TEXT = {
  'access_request': '%(user_name)s has requested to access your document %(story_name)s, please review '}
```

I saw the google translate feature and it perfectly translates if given the final sentence understanding the user_name and story_name are constant. 
I was looking for a similar magic band functionality in Django where I can just wrap final message before sending to the user in the locale received in the `Accept-language` header of the `REST` call. But this doesn't seem possible.

As I understand I would need to pre-mark the text which needs to be translated with `ugettext` and define language and middleware settings. Then generate `locale` specific files using

`django-admin makemessages -l de`

and then in the generated `django.po` file for that specific locale gives the translated text manually for Django to refer.

But I am stuck how to mark given my message is dynamic, inside a dic. Or is there another way around?

Edit:

The data is accessed as below

```
data['msg'] = settings.NOTIFICATION_TEXT['access_request'] % \
              dict(
                user_name=get_user_name(sender),
                story_name=story.story_name
              )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply the appropriate translation function to the message before inserting the dynamic context, in this case (module level, I assume) that would be one of the lazy ones:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

NOTIFICATION_TEXT = {
  'access_request': _('%(user_name)s has requested to access your document %(story_name)s, please review ')
}
```

`makemessages -l de` will then create an entry in the locale's django.po:

```
msgid "%(user_name)s has requested to access your document %(story_name)s, please review "
msgstr ""
```

The translated string must contain all the dynamic placeholders unchanged:

```
msgid "%(user_name)s has requested to access your document %(story_name)s, please review "
msgstr "%(user_name)s hat Zugang zu Ihrem Dokument %(story_name)s beantragt, bitte überprüfen Sie "
```

It is important to apply the (`user_name`, `story_name`) context to the message **after** applying the translation function, which your architecture pretty much already enforces at this time:

```
message = NOTIFICATION_TEXT['access_request'] % {'user_name': 'foo', 'story_name': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Ok, now I have the `django.po` file with the above `msgid` and have inserted the `msgstr` but it still not translating the final text. In my `settings.py` file I have `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'`,  `USE_I18N = True`, In the middlewares I have added `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',` after Sesssion and before Common. Not sure if they help but just in case.

Comment: Looks right to me. You should add debugging to check which language is activated. You might try it in the django shell and manually activate German. (`django.utils.translation.activate('de')`). BTW, have you called `compilemessages`?

Comment: Ran `compilemessages` now, and manually activated `de`, testing from shell but not getting translated string. What you meant my, I had to apply the context after applying the translation function?

Comment: I meant you should not do `_('%(xy)s' % {'xy': 'foo'})`, but always  `_('%(xy)s') % {'xy': 'foo'}`. So you first translate the message with the placeholders and only then fill the placeholders with content, not the other way round because then the message will contain arbitrary stuff and won't be recognized.

Comment: do I also need to apply translation while accessing the data. I added how my data is being accessed.

Comment: Have you wrapped the message in the translation function as indicated in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155500/discussion-between-garg10may-and-schwobaseggl).